# Logo img crashes Bootstrap navbar in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I won't write long, jus show you.(Without img everything is good)

IE screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1dn6ss1ue5y2c9/ie_screen.png

Normal browser:
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/bp0spch1yvowglp/chrome_screen.png

HTML code:

```
   <div class="topbar"> 
<div class="navbar ">
     <div class="container">                 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">       
      <li><%= link_to "Overview",    root_path %></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About",    about_path %></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "What we do", what_we_do_path %></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Partners", partners_path %></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
   </div>
```

My CSS :

```
.container{
background-color: white;
width: 960px;
}

.navbar .nav {
background-color: white;
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
 }

.navbar .nav .active > a, .navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: white;
}

 .navbar .nav img{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: The img tag isn't in the HTML above...

Comment: @denmed you should edit your post to remove the Dropbox links since they are no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view:

```
    <%= link_to(image_tag("/images/logo.png"), root_path, id: "logo") %>
```

Css:

```
#logo{
float:left;
}
```